# Taking pictures and recording multimedia files from WPF-application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multimedia

we are in need of a way to record videos with sound and taking pictures inside a WPF-application. It should be able to save locally to disk. Preferably it should be able to show the content once it is saved as well, but if no such component exists, we will use another component for the playback.

I've looked around and found no real good options to do this. Some options lack the sound recording in videos, and some are just too old to get working properly (WPF has had a long run so far...)

Does anyone here has any experience in this specific area?

Answer (score 0):

Got Taking Pictures and Videos working with this little documentation https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/330177/Yet-another-Web-Camera-control

If you dont tell us what problems exactly you got, or which code you already got, we can't really help.

Comment: That one was actually a new library for us, but I can't really get it to capture videos with audio to file.